# How to 'queue' piece of code in javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I've made a class that, when initialized, starts to download a JSON file.

However, the downloading runs asynchronously.
So after I declare it I start working with it, but it fails because it hasn't loaded the file yet.

I could turn async off, but is there another way without freezing the browser?

I'm currently working around it with a setTimeout option, but that seems like an ugly hack.

```
  var d;
  $(document).ready(function() {
      d = new Duk('element');
      d.getBlueprint('hud.json');
      setTimeout(start, '2000');
  });

  function start(){
      test = new d.Dialog(d.blueprint.screens.test);
      test.draw();
  }
```

Comment: Why are you passing a string as the second argument to `setTimeout`?  Obviously it will be coerced to a number, but why not just use a numeric literal in the first place?

Comment: What library are you using? What is a `Duk` and what does `getBlueprint()` do?

Answer (score 1):

You have to attach event handler to the object load completion event. The library you are working with must supply this event. I don't know what a `Duk` is, or what `getBlueprint()` does, but you should check the documentation for whatever that class and method is, and see if there is an oncomplete callback. If there is, you'd do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    d = new Duk('element');
    d.getBlueprint('hud.json', {
        onComplete: function() {
            test = new d.Dialog(d.blueprint.screens.test);
            test.draw();
        }
    });
});
```

Obviously, I just made that up. I don't know if your library has an onComplete method defined like this, but I hope you see what I mean. Without knowing more about the library you are using, I can't give a better example.

Answer (score 0):

Timeouts are not the way to solve this problem.

You want to set up a callback function alongside the request so that the object handling the request knows what to do when the response comes in.

It is unclear from your code what framework you're using (I can't make any sense of `getBlueprint`, which seems to be the call that initializes the remote request), so if you could provide more information on this, we can provide more customized help.

Answer (score 0):

You want your getBlueprint() method to be able to accept a callback which is run when the file is finished downloading.

```
function getBlueprint(file, callback)
{
    // do whatever to get the file
    // ...
    // trigger the callback
    callback();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var d;
    function start(){
        test = new d.Dialog(d.blueprint.screens.test);
        test.draw();
    }
    d = new Duk('element');
    d.getBlueprint('hud.json', start);
    setTimeout(start, '2000');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree that a callback function is the proper way. If this is code you cannot modify, you can do something like this, but seriously, **use a callback!**

```
function wait_for_load(expr, func)
{
    var interval = window.setInterval(function()
    {
        if(eval(expr))
        {
            window.clearInterval(interval);
            func();
        }
    }, 20);
}

var d;
$(document).ready(function() {
    d = new Duk('element');
    d.getBlueprint('hud.json');
    wait_for_load('d.blueprint', start);
});
```